# Google Apps Script function fails with OAuth2 permission issue only when called on another user

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an Apps Script project that uses a service account to make changes to users' Gmail settings, to do things like enable forwarding after an employee leaves the company. I have a function that modifies a forwarding address (1) and then another function that calls this later(2). With some users, but not all, (2) fails.

```
Callback from forward address creation: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

What's going on? All this started when I realized that (2), which runs on a schedule, was no longer working. I have no idea what scope it's saying I don't have access to use. The Apps Script app runs as a super admin account and the associated service account has Domain wide delegation access. I have all of the Gmail scopes in my appscript.json as well as the gmail service enabled. I don't know why it's working on some users but not others. I tried clearing the now-deprecated Properties store but that also didn't seem to work.

(1)

```
const gmailSuperScope = ['https://mail.google.com/'];
const gmailSharingScope = ['https://mail.google.com/', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic'];


function modifyForwardingAddress(formObject) {
  var forwarder = formObject.forwarder;
  var recipient = formObject.recipient;
  var option = formObject.forwardOption;
  console.log(forwarder+recipient+option);
  var method = null;
  var service = getService_(forwarder, 'gmail', gmailSuperScope); //fails with the same error with gmailSharingScope 

  if (option == 'delete') {
    var url = 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/' + forwarder + '/settings/forwardingAddresses/' + recipient;
    // no body required
    var payload = null;
    method = 'delete';
    console.log("attempting to delete: " + url);
  }
  else if (option == 'create') {
    var url = 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/' + forwarder + '/settings/forwardingAddresses';
    var payload = {
      forwardingEmail: recipient,
      verificationStatus: 'accepted'
    }
    method = 'post';
  }

  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    console.info('Serivce has access. Continuing...');
    // If we're creating a forwarding address, we will also auto-enable it:
    if (option == 'create') {
      console.info('Creating new pair...');
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, (requestBuilder(service, payload, method))); // this creates the forwarding address
      var result = response.getContentText();
      console.log("Callback from forward address creation: " + result);
      writeAuditLogItem("Set Forwarding Addresses from " + forwarder + " to " + recipient, forwarder);
      url = 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/' + forwarder + '/settings/autoForwarding';
      payload = {
        enabled: true,
        emailAddress: recipient,
        disposition: 'leaveInInbox'
      }
      method = 'put';
      var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, (requestBuilder(service, payload, method)));
      console.log(response2.getContentText());
    }
    else if (option == 'delete') {
      console.info('Deleting pair...');
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, (requestBuilderNoPayload(service, method)));
      deleteResponse = response.getContentText()
      console.info(deleteResponse);
    }
    else {
      console.info('You should not see this.');
    }
  } else {
    console.log(service);
  }
}
```

(2) fails with error

```
var payloadObj = {
    forwarder: user.primaryEmail,
    recipient: managerEmail,
    forwardOption: 'create'
    }
console.info("Enabling forwarding for: " + user.primaryEmail);
createFwdFilter(user.primaryEmail, managerEmail);
modifyForwardingAddress(payloadObj);
}
```

Helper fucntions:

```
function getService_(email, service, scopes) {// the _ means the function is private and cannot be called from the UI 
  return OAuth2.createService(service + ':' + email)
    // Set the endpoint URL.
    .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')

    // Set the private key and issuer.
    .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
    .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

    // Set the name of the user to impersonate.
    .setSubject(email)

    // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

    // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
    // setup of domain-wide delegation.
    .setScope(scopes);
}
function requestBuilder(service, payload, method) {
  return {
    method: method,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
}
```

Comment: Hi `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing` scope is required when creating forward address and when calling auto-forwarding. could you include the definition of `getService_()` and `requestBuilder()` to check how did you set your oauth scopes and your url options

Comment: @RonM thanks for taking a look, I added the helper functions. The script will fail with the gmailSharingScope passed to the function as well.

Comment: @AlanWells That blog post refers to the Groups APIs, this is calling the Gmail settings API on behalf of a user which still does require DWD to my knowledge.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: I commented out the line I coped from the OAuth2 library example code that says `.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())` so nothing would be cached and the issue was fixed instantly. I'm trying to figure out why this occurred.

Comment: Adding a note here for posterity, but it was not a code issue. I unfortunately forgot what I changed on the google side.